# Tensorflow how to get the mapping relation between input and output if input is randomly shuffled by tf.data.TFRecordDataset

Tags: tensorflow

Given the input data `user_vector`, each row of `user_vector` is the vector of one user, users are unique. Read the input data by tf.data.TFRecordDataset and randomly shuffle it, now we get `shuffled_user_vector`. Suppose the `shuffled_user_vector` goes through a neural network and becomes `user_embedding`. My question is how to map the `user_vector` to `user_embedding`, i.e. which rows in `user_vector` and `user_embedding` point to the same user?

Should I keep the indices of shuffled user vector? Or is there better solution of tensorflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `user-id` property into the data pipeline (before shuffling) and, when doing prediction, return this property together with the user_embedding.